# Natural logarithmic function properties

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, logarithms

I'm just curious if $-\ln(\cos(x))$ is equivalent to $\ln((\cos(x))^{-1})$? I know the properties of the natural logarithmic function. I just don't know if the property also implies the signs.

Therefore, if the $\ln$ is raised to $e$ would it result to $1/\cos(x)$ since cosine is now raised to $-1$?

Answer (score 1):

A standard property of the logarithm is that $log(a^n) = n\times log(a)$, with the caveat that $log(x)$ is not defined for any $ x \leq 0$. For any $cos(x) > 0$ , $log(cos(x)^{-1}) = -log(cos(x))$.

So $e^{log(cos(x)^{-1})} = cos(x)^{-1} = e^{-log(cos(x))}$, so long as $cos(x) > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with “equivalent”? They're *equal* (when $\cos x>0$, of course), because $x>0\implies\ln\left(\frac1x\right)=-\ln x$.